# How to use LINQ to filter property which is not null and get its value to run a method?

Tags: c#

How do I create LINQ to call `DoSomething()` only once to reduce these duplicate codes? Note that there are some properties in `nameValue` which I don't need to do anything about it. `DoSomething()` is only applied for these 4 properties.

```
foreach (var nameValue in nameDetails.NameValue)
{ 
    if (nameValue.FirstName != null)
    {                                                       
        DoSomething(nameValue.FirstName)
    }

    if (nameValue.MaidenName != null)
    {
        DoSomething(nameValue.MaidenName)
    }

    if (nameValue.MiddleName != null)
    {
        DoSomething(nameValue.MiddleName)                           
    }

    if (nameValue.Surname != null)
    {
        DoSomething(nameValue.Surname)  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create an array of *names, then use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0) to flatten 2 dimensional array into `IEnumerable<string>` , e.g.:

```
var enumerable = nameDetails.NameValue.SelectMany(elem => new[]
{
    elem.FirstName,
    elem.MaidenName,
    elem.MiddleName,
    elem.Surname
}).Where(value => value != null);

foreach (var value in enumerable)
{
    DoSomething(value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the condition into the function and you can write

```
foreach (var nameValue in nameDetails.NameValue)
{                                                      
    DoSomethingMaybe(nameValue.FirstName);
    DoSomethingMaybe(nameValue.MaidenName);
    DoSomethingMaybe(nameValue.MiddleName);
    DoSomethingMaybe(nameValue.Surname);      
}

void DoSomethingMaybe(string value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {                                                       
        DoSomething(value)
    }
}
```

perfectly readable and no unnecessary overhead, no throwaway objects. Maybe not the answer you expect, but LINQ is not magic, that makes things better just be being there.

Comment: Nice and simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation of your question is that you want to *write* `DoSomething` only once but still want to *perform* it more than once if more than one name part is not null.

You can refactor your code to this:

```cs
var names = nameDetails.NameValue
    .SelectMany(nv => new string[] { nv.FirstName, nv.MaidenName, nv.MiddleName, nv.Surname })
    .Where(name => name != null);

foreach (var name in names)
{
    DoSomething(name);
}
```

This makes use of [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany) which allows each item of the source enumerable to be mapped into multiple values which are then flattened into an enumerable of the mapped element value's type.